# Series color in Jaspersoft 6.2 Highchart - Scatter

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've created a scatter highchart in Jaspersoft Server 6.2 (called ad hoc reports in the product) but encountered a strange problem where I cannot get normal color related properties to take effect. I normally just the property: colors ["#999999"] to other types of charts in Jaspersoft Server but for some reason this does not work in a scatter chart, I also tried using rgba values in the property.

I have searched extensively for a solution and everything that seems to apply to normal highcharts doesn't appear to work in Jaspersoft Server. I've tried adding the following properties:

- series.color
- series.data.color
- series.marker.color
- plotOptions.scatter.color

With hex and rgba values defined but the data points either remain black or disappear altogether. It's something that's very easy to manipulate in other chart types but scatter chart tye seems quite restrictive in Jaspersoft so perhaps not. Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: Sorry I should point out I'm using the ad hoc reports in Jaspersoft Server not Studio but the Studio tag was the only Jaspersoft one available.

Comment: The right one is [tag:jasper-reports]